# Extract imdb id with perl regex query

Tags: regex, perl

```
{
"initial_release_date": "1982-12-17",
"imdb_id": [
"tt0086617"
],
"type": "/film/film",
"timestamp": "2006-10-22T09:26:51.0012Z",
"name": "The Year of Living Dangerously",
"mid": "/m/07hvh"
}
],'
```

I would like to extract an imdb id from a JSON query with a perl REGEX query. Does anybody know how?...

Comment: If you already have the data in JSON, you should extract it with JSON.

Comment: I want to do it from this text with perl regex. This is example text

Comment: We don't do very well solving example problems.  We're much better at solving actual problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $myString = 'initial_release_date": "1982-12-17", "imdb_id": [ "tt0086617" ], "type": "/film/film", "timestamp": "2006-10-22T09:26:51.0012Z", "name": "The Year of Living Dangerously", "mid": "/m/07hvh" }';

if($myString =~ /"imdb_id":\s+\[\s+"(.*?)"\s+\]/i){
print  $1;
#tt0086617
}
```

Comment: Just for thought, I would use `\s*` instead of an actual space here. And add the `i` modifier for case insensitive matching.

Comment: @hwnd I had the insensitive case on my original regex but didn't past it here, changed, tks